# Good tools/techniques for identifying the format of a headerless audio file?

Tags: audio, format, computer-forensics

I have some audio files that are in this mystery format I can't quite figure out. Here is a list of things I have tried:

- Opening them up with a Hex Editor
- [Gary Kessler's File Signatures list](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html)
- Audacity (opened as raw data)
- Awave Studio
- [SoX (Sound eXchange)](http://sox.sourceforge.net)
- [TrID](https://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html)
- [DROID](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/information-management/manage-information/preserving-digital-records/droid/)

Thanks to [the answer by nneonneo](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-should-i-determine-the-format-of-this-audio-file) here it sounds like my samples are somewhere between a typical compressed format and a speech format.

[Here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/948915144606515220/952419340429451315/EV_000_200_013.android) is an example, and [this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/948915144606515220/952421214062772264/munchie-sticks-his-head-out.mp3) is what it should sound like. I'm at a loss for anything else I can try- most suggestions i've seen in my searches don't seem to work for headerless formats like this.

I would be delighted if anyone knows of any good tools or even if there was a paid service available for something like this.

Comment: How do know it is headerless - it may just have a header you don't recognise, surely? How do you know how it sounds? How well does the example match the *real* sound - are they identical in duration? Is there other noise on the *real* sound? Do you have other samples?

Comment: Thanks a bunch for replying, I really appreciate it.

HXD (hex editor) didn't show a particularly recognizable header. I did all kinds of searching for any kind of header magic, dozens of applications meant for this as well, but couldn't find anything more on it at the time. 

There are numerous other samples I have. The "what it should sound like" is the output from the application that reads it, so slightly degraded from what it would be as a direct rip. Unfortunately, this application is closed-source

At this point, however, we've been able to work around it.